# Unable to find 'javascript.swg'

Tags: swig

I am building a C++ library with Swig, I get this error on mac-os.
Any help would be appreciated.

Swig was installed via homebrew.

Unable to find 'javascript.swg'

Comment: I think you forgot to include the error you are getting.

Comment: Unable to find 'javascript.swg'

Comment: You should edit your answer to include this. Some people who can help may not read the comments.

Comment: I have put the error message on the title of the question, I have edited on the body as well

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by installing a different version of swig.